# treat c:/name.txt like file:///C:/name.txt in firefox

Tags: firefox

I am used to open my website links online in Internet Explorer, and then remove the http:// with c:/ where the sitename is the same on my local folders
example:

```
http://sitename.com/dir/page1.html
```

change it to

```
c:/sitename.com/dir/page1.html
```

so it opens the local page directly, and through a button I could edit what is needed in my local version of the page..

However this behavior doesn't work in Firefox (I have ver. 14.0.1)
as to view the local file, I have to type "file:///" before the "c:/"

and when I write "c:/" directly in Firefox, I get the following error:

```
The address wasn't understood

Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (c) isn't
associated with any program.

You might need to install other software to open this address.
```

So, is there a way to let Firefox understand c:/ or d:/ or treat local drives as "file:///"?  like Windows Explorer (as it is interchangeable with ie)..

Comment: While I know its not the answer you want, it might be worth noting that chrome has this feature.

Comment: yes you are right..  but I am trying to move all my work to one browser, so Firefox seems to have many of what I need..

Answer (score 0):

Using backslashes work.

C:\ instead of C:/

Comment: yes it works with that slash \ but, if the link has more than one / I have to change each one of them!  if it is sitename.com/book/file.html it won't work, I'll have to change all the slashes!

Comment: or can I let Firefox treat the \ as / and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but it should work in theory.

1. Install [URL Suffix extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/url-suffix/).
2. Configure it to automatically append "file:///" on any link you navigate to with CTRL+ENTER (or any other shortcut).
3. Now when you want to access a local file, just press CTRL+ENTER (or the shortcut you chose) after you have changed it to C:/.